# Netbeans, Adding Glasfish server "does not exist"

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

When adding a Glassfish Server, the following shows
[image: Does not exist]

It seems to be a new problem since I can't find anyone else with the same issue.
Anyone else with this problem?

Answer (score 5):

**Updated 4/19/18:**

I raised a bug report for this issue: [NETBEANS-997 Unable to download and create GlassFish server](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-997). It is fixed in NetBeans 11.0.

Also see [NETBEANS-997 Fix for unable to download and create GlassFish server / support for installing GF 4.1.2 & GF 5.0](https://github.com/apache/incubator-netbeans/pull/1119)

(End of update)

---

I can replicate your problem when downloading GlassFish as part of the process of adding the GlassFish server. In my case, this is what happened:

- I selected an existing **Installation Location** folder to contain the download of GlassFish, named **C:\Users\johndoe\GFDownload**
- I received a *Download & Install completed...* message, followed by the *Does not exist* error, just as you did.
- The folder I had created (**C:\Users\johndoe\GFDownload**) was renamed as **C:\Users\johndoe\GFDownload1** and contained a single empty file named **foo4126589950858116700.tmp**.

So this looks like a bug in NetBeans: if there is an error during the process of downloading GlassFish then NetBeans renames your **Installation Location** folder, and incorrectly reports *Download & Install completed...*.

In your case, check to see whether NetBeans renamed your **Installation Location** folder as **E:Users\Wouter\Glassfish_Server1**.

Since this issue is occurring on Oracle's 8.x version of NetBeans, and NetBeans has now been handed over to Apache, I doubt that the problem will be fixed. However, there is a simple workaround:

- First, download Glassfish directly from the [GlassFish download page](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download).
- Then specify the folder containing the download of GlassFish as the **Installation Location** in the **Add Server Instance** screen.

Answer (score 3):

Another options is install a different Netbeans 8.2 bundle [here](https://netbeans.org/downloads/)
[image]
And avoid this issue. For example "java EE bundle" or "All bundle"

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you have downloaded the Netbeans without the Glassfish server.
You can get the Netbeans with the Glassfish server from this link.

[Netbeans with Glassfish](https://netbeans.org/downloads/old/8.2/start.html?platform=windows&lang=en&option=all)

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened and what I did was manually downloaded Glassfish from https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download

And choose Full Platform. After downloading paste it somewhere and extract

Then when Adding the server, Click Browse and select the extracted file. Then it will detect it and say something like
"Detected a GlassFish Server 5.0 install. Click Next to register remote or custom local domains."

Then the problem will be solved. :3